# Using pymssql library - Query returning unknown values even though there isn't any value available?

Tags: python, sql, tuples, pymssql

I'm a newbie in python and all things web development. So please go easy on me :).

I have a piece of code below ->

```
import pymssql

tupleA = [(1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d), (5,e)]

con = pymssql.connect('server', 'username', 'pass', 'db')
cur = con.cursor()

onlyNumber = [x[0] for x in tupleA]
onlyLetter = [x[1] for x in tupleA]

querystring = """
    select COUNT(hl.id), h.number_id from h
    left join hl on hl.h_id = h.id
    left join l on l.id = hl.l_id
    where h.number_id in (%s) and l.letter_id in (%s)
    GROUP by h.number_id
    """ % (','.join(map(str, onlyNumber)), ','.join(map(str, onlyLetter)))

cur.execute(querystring)

numberOfHl = []
number = []

for row in cur:
    numberOfHl.append(row[0])
    number.append(row[1])

setThree = zip(numberOfHl, number)

print setThree

con.close()
```

The above code is returning unknown values, especially for numberOfHl i.e. [(**11**,1),(**9**,2),(**5**,3),(**12**,4),(**10**,5)] because I know when I run that query in SQL it returns no values.

What am I doing wrong here? Does my query needs to change and handle null values properly? By adding .join am I creating those unknown values?

Please any help will be appreciated. Again I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge in programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is occurring but you're doing it slightly wrong.
You should prepare the query string with placeholders first:

```
querystring = """
    select COUNT(hl.id), h.number_id from h
    left join hl on hl.h_id = h.id
    left join l on l.id = hl.l_id
    where h.number_id in (%s) and l.letter_id in (%s)
    GROUP by h.number_id
    """ % (','.join(len(onlyNumber)*['%s']), ','.join(len(onlyLetter)*['%s']))
```

Result:

```
>>> print(querystring)

    select COUNT(hl.id), h.number_id from h
    left join hl on hl.h_id = h.id
    left join l on l.id = hl.l_id
    where h.number_id in (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) and l.letter_id in (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
    GROUP by h.number_id
```

So then you have your placeholders and you can pass the values as the second argument to `.execute()` like so:

```
 cur.execute(querystring,tuple(onlyNumber + onlyLetter))
```

Comment: Thank you @bernie. Not sure if it's going to solve my problem but I will give that a go.

Comment: one quick question - why did you use onlyNumber + onlyLetter at the endline?
I'm currently getting an error --> ValueError: 'params' arg (<type 'list'>) can be only a tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: Ah let me fix that.

Comment: Ok try that out.

Comment: Thank you @bernie